# I need either mathematical solution or programming solution in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, matrix, mathematical-optimization

I am thinking to arrange office room.
Office room is always noisy, and you are thinking to separate each room users as possible as you
can so that they don’t feel uncomfortable.

If they are facing each other, we will add unhappy point as 1.

INPUT
What we can do here is based on given rooms and users, arrange room separately so people don’t
feel uncomfortable.
[row, column, users] -> unhappy points

> Example 1: [2, 3, 6]
> *2 Rows, 3 Columns, 6 people
>
> Example 2: [3, 3, 8]
> *3 Rows, 3 Columns, 8 people

Sample Output

[image]]

Following are some Test Cases :

> [5,2,8]-> 7
>
> [3,5,14]-> 18
>
> [1,16,1]-> 0
>
> [3,5,1]-> 0
>
> [8,2,12]-> 10
>
> [16,1,1]-> 0
>
> [3,3,6]-> 3
>
> [2,6,12]-> 16
>
> [15,1,0]-> 0
>
> [5,3,7]-> 0
>
> [4,3,5]-> 0

I need either mathematical solution or programming solution in PHP.

Comment: This appears to be "do my work for me". Such services are done by contractors for payment, rather than StackOverflow for free.

Comment: Do you have any proposed solution? The purpose this site isn't to write code for you, but to help you on the way.

Comment: I have tried out some mathematical logic and tried some PHP scripts but do not get any proper solution. So I asked my question here.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete question because how will you determine that two rooms are facing each other and one more thing is that how are you counting 7 unhappy points for first example.
I've observes that if you are taking a matrix lets say 4 by 5 than you can put 4*5=20 peoples there.So how will you count more than 20 points while we have only 20 people?

Comment: This seems as N queen problem with X*Y matrix where N<=X*Y